# Android studio, Error: cannot find symbol. I am trying to use an mp4 file to play a video inside my app

Tags: android, android-studio, mp4

I want to have a dedicated button in order to play videos on my page. I have written down the following code. Is it something wrong with it? When I try to build my app in a virtual device, this error shows up:

error: cannot find symbol

String videopath = "android.resource://com.example.royale_assistant/"+R.raw.pekkavid;

```
                                                              ^
```

symbol:   variable pekkavid

location: class raw

This is my code at the moment.`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);
    clk1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    videov1 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    imageButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this,MainActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
public void videoplay(View b)
{
    String videopath = "android.resource://com.example.royale_assistant/"+R.raw.pekkavid;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
    videov1.setVideoURI(uri);
    videov1.start();
}
```

}`

Thank you in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Ok just make changes in your `videopath` file. Add the below code in your `videopath` file.

```
String videopath = ""file:///android_res/raw/pekkavid" 
// if above code not work, then add .mp4 after your video file as below
String videopath = ""file:///android_res/raw/pekkavid.mp4"
```

I only suggest you use `MediaPlayer` to play videos. It is very simple to play videos. If the problem is the same, let me know